# How is (if it is) gauge symmetry realized in chiral perturbation theory?

Tags: quantum-chromodynamics, effective-field-theory

I often read that an effective field theory must have the symmetries of its UV completion. Chiral perturbation theory is an Effective Field Theory (EFT) of QCD. I know that the approximate chiral symmetry of QCD is realized in the chiral perturbation theory, but I wonder to what extent the $SU(3)$ gauge symmetry is realized. I mean, a gauge transformation is a transformation on the quarks and the gluons. These fields are absent in chiral QCD, so how is gauge symmetry realized in chiral perturbation theory?

Comment: The fundamental degrees of freedom in chiral perturbation theory are hadrons, which are color-singlet (gauge-invariant) combinations of quarks, as a result of confinement. So the answer to your question is that the gauge symmetry is realized trivially in chiral perturbation theory.